# Setup for navigation in wpf and mvvmlight

Tags: mvvm-light

Currently getting started on a new wpf project and want to use mvvmlight. My initial thought was to have 4 buttons as navigation at top of the window and then a contentcontrol where new views would be injected when chosen from the navigationbuttions.

That is a mainwindow and som subviews that will be injected. The main VM should have commands hooked to wired up with the navigation buttons. When executed the command should send a navigation message to change a view, and this is where I get confused. Who should handle the navigation messages send and change the view in the ContentControl? I guess the ViewModelLocator is only for instantiating the viewmodels.

What is missing in getting this glued together?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595312/creating-an-mvvm-friendly-dialog-strategy/6603347#6603347) for a dialog strategy. This should be applicable to your problem. However, one word of caution when using messages in the above szenario ... **call Unregistr()** especially on your views.