# How can I close a Silverlight child from the ViewModel?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, viewmodel, childwindow

I have a child window that is used for logging in. Previously, a large portion of the code was in the Window's code behind. I refactored all of it to fit the MVVM model. Which it's all working, except I can't close the child window when it's done.

I've looked into how to accomplish this from the VM, but everything I've tried hasn't ended up working.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you handling opening the window to start with?

Answer (score 2):

Add `Finished` event to view model. Call `OnFinished` method when you need to close.

```
public event EventHandler Finished;
protected void OnFinished()
{
    if (Finished != null)
        Finished(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

From code behind of child window subscribe to event and actually close the window.

```
ViewModel.Finished += (s, e) => Close();
```

#### See also

> [Creating an MVVM friendly dialog strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595312/creating-an-mvvm-friendly-dialog-strategy)

Comment: Could even do this through an interface, e.g. IModalViewModel or something.