# How to implement Dialog with/without feedback in an wpf 4.0 application using MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Can someone please guide me towards how to implement Custom Dialog for displaying Errors or simple messages to the UI and recieving response back without violating MVVM. I am in badly need of this. Please help me out.

Thanks,
Zafar

Comment: What do you mean by *violating MVVM*?

Comment: It is with least code behind and reusability.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to exchange data(errors)  from view to viewmodel loosly coupled? Then the Messenger class is the way to go

Comment: I want some sort of Coustomizable Message box with some predefined functionality to show message in MVVM way so that I can access those message boxes from any of my viewmodel.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to your comment I strongly suggest you take a close look at the [Messenger class](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cf8d07c2ec3f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Messaging/Messenger.cs). It even provides GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.[DialogMessage](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cf8d07c2ec3f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Messaging/DialogMessage.cs) type for this purpose. But you can provide your custom ones be subclassing `GenericMessage<T>`

You register for a message like this and define what should happen on arrival of a message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(this,
    dm =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dm.Content, dm.Caption, dm.Button, dm.Icon);
    });
```

Although there is only a WeakReference hold, i tend to unregister if I dont want to be informed anymore or the view is discarded. Always be a good citizen ;)

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
```

Send a message to the receiver and optionally define a callback to get back the dialogresult:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new DialogMessage(this, "Content",
    result => Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()))
    {
        Caption = "Caption"
        Icon = MessageBoxImage.Asterisk,
        Button = MessageBoxButton.OK
    });
```

Comment: By using the same approach, one can display the custom dialog but it will add some complexity.

Answer (score 0):

To handle any kind of dialog stuff within the mvvm pattern, you should go with a kind of Dialog-Service. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595312/creating-an-mvvm-friendly-dialog-strategy) you will find some hints to go with this approach.

Putting dialog stuff into a service keeps the mvvm pattern untouched. The service takes care of all the creation of the dialogs and can provide the results. The view-model just calls methods and subscribes events provided by a service.

A good way to solve your problem this way is using the [User Interaction Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec10).

> In terms of the MVVM pattern, the view model is responsible for initiating an interaction with the user and for consuming and processing any response, while the view is responsible for actually managing the interaction with the user using whatever user experience is appropriate. Preserving the separation of concerns between the presentation logic implemented in the view model, and the user experience implemented by the view, helps to improve testability and flexibility.
>
> There are two common approaches to implementing these kinds of user interactions in the MVVM pattern. One approach is to implement a service that can be used by the view model to initiate interaction with the user, thereby preserving its independence on the view's implementation. Another approach uses events raised by the view model to express the intent to interact with the user, along with components in the view that are bound to these events and that manage the visual aspects of the interaction.

This is a MVVM pattern for doing DialogServices etc. so it will fit your requirement, too.